# contains filter value in 1st column of table only

Tags: jquery

```
$('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').not(':contains('+ filterVal + ')').hide();
```

I'm trying to hide all the rows in my table where it doesn't have the filter value in it.  Everything is working ok but my table contains multiple columns and it is doing a search in the entire table.  So if the filter value shows up in column 2 then that is not hidden.  I really only want it to check in column 1.  Then I want to hide the entire row if it doesn't contain that value in column 1.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest solution be to give the cells in your first column a class and then target the class?

Comment: @j08691 As this is a legacy app I don't really have that option at this time.  I'm hoping for a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').not(':contains(' + filterVal + ')').parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
$("#MainContent_myTable tr").filter(function() {
        return ($(this).find('td:first:contains("B")').length == 0);
    }).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/NwKcg/1/